# Unexplained DIV at bottom of page causing whitespace

Tags: html, css

Please see attached [image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZg1g.png)

I will also include the code below, although this is a 3-page site I will just provide the contact page HTML to keep it shorter. The issue is across all pages. I am hoping that the image provides enough info so you don't have to go through the whole code.

I have created a few sites now and sometimes run into this issue. The VH's all add up to 100, making the site 1 page which should be unscrollable however that appears to not be the case. Can anyone advise on what this div is at the bottom of the page and how I can remove it?

HTML Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h4,
h5 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

li,
button,
label,
input,
p,
a {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.main-head {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 60%;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav .logo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 10rem;
          flex: 1 1 10rem;
}

nav .logo h1 {
  margin: 2rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 40rem;
          flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

.intro {
  max-height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 5%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.intro h2 {
  font-size: 8rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#38d39f), to(#38a4d3));
  background: linear-gradient(left, #38d39f, #38a4d3);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: inline-block;
}

.intro h3 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}

.intro p {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  color: #2c2c2c;
}

.intro svg {
  width: 95%;
}

.splash {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.intro-social {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.intro-social a {
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.active {
  background: #2c2c2c;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.intro-text {
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
      -ms-flex: 2 1 40rem;
          flex: 2 1 40rem;
}

.intro-images {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 40rem;
          flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

#plant-left {
  -webkit-animation: plant 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          animation: plant 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

#plant-right {
  -webkit-animation: plant 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate 0.75s;
          animation: plant 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate 0.75s;
}

#me {
  -webkit-animation: me 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          animation: me 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
          transform-origin: bottom;
}

#clock-arrow {
  -webkit-animation: clock 1.5s infinite linear;
          animation: clock 1.5s infinite linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
          transform-origin: bottom;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes plant {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2%);
            transform: translateY(-2%);
  }
}

@keyframes plant {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2%);
            transform: translateY(-2%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes me {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(10deg);
            transform: rotateZ(10deg);
  }
}

@keyframes me {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
            transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(10deg);
            transform: rotateZ(10deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes clock {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes clock {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.projects {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.travelly,
.elena-joy {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 40rem;
          flex: 1 1 40rem;
  margin: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.travelly h2,
.elena-joy h2 {
  margin: auto auto 5rem auto;
}

.form-section {
  height: 80vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0rem 0rem 0rem 0rem;
}

.form-section form {
  padding: 3rem 10rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.form-section form input,
.form-section form textarea {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.form-section form input:focus,
.form-section form textarea:focus {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.form-section form textarea {
  font-family: "montserrat" sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.form-section form button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: #154343;
  color: white;
}

.form-section form button:focus {
  background: #9999d6;
}

footer {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 10vh;
  padding: 0% 5%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
      flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

footer h4 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 3;
      -ms-flex: 3 1 40rem;
          flex: 3 1 40rem;
}

footer ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 1 40rem;
          flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

footer ul li {
  padding: 0rem 5rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1364px) {
  html {
    font-size: 53%;
  }
  .splash {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 754px) {
  html {
    font-size: 45%;
  }
  svg {
    height: 60%;
  }
  .main-head {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  .intro-text {
    margin: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .intro-images {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .intro-social {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
  }
  .intro-social a {
    margin: 2rem;
  }
  .elena-joy img,
  .travelly img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  form {
    padding: 0rem;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  form textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 641px) {
  footer h4 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .form-section form {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 20px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 20px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Jason Cleaver | Bespoke Web Design</title>
      <meta
          name="description"
          content="Jason Cleaver is a front-end web developer who specialised in HTML and CSS"
      />
      <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
      <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
      />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
      <header class="main-head">
          <nav>
              <div class="logo">
                  <img src="../icons/code.svg" alt="logo" />
                  <h1>Jason Cleaver</h1>
              </div>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../projects/">Projects</a></li>
                  <li><a class="active" href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>
      <section class="form-section">
          <form>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
              <label for="message">Message</label>
              <textarea
                  name="message"
                  id="message"
                  cols="50"
                  rows="10"
              ></textarea>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
      </section>
      <footer>
          <h4>Jason Cleaver &copy; 2021</h4>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#"
                      ><img src="../icons/twitter 1.svg" alt="twitter-social"
                  /></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#"
                      ><img
                          src="../icons/instagram 1.svg"
                          alt="instagram-social"
                  /></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#"
                      ><img
                          src="../icons/youtube-symbol 1.svg"
                          alt="youtube-social"
                  /></a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: It seems to come from "Code injected by live-server". So you should turn off that live-server, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I don't have any whitespace... it may be a problem due to live server, try to open your file directly in your web browser (without using liveserver)